# the form of dt - Is the pronunciation the same?

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics

Here are the same Schrödinger equations with different forms of "d" - the first one is a curved form.

The question of this thread is: Do you pronounce this curved form of "d" still as /d/?

> [image: A partial differential equation]

> [image: A differential equation]

> [image: Another partial differential equation]

Comment: I don't know how to pronounce it, but it's called **partial differential**, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in a document on how to read mathematical expressions.

http://par.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/link/Mathe-pronun.pdf

They suggest it is to be read as d or that you should read the whole thing out in words, the partial derivative of ... with respect to ...

Although the document comes from a French institution I believe it represents the practice of English speaking mathematicians.

Comment: Yeah... Also read the first paragraph of [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%82): 'read as *"the partial derivative of z with respect to x"*'

Comment: @mdewey. Thank you. I've read through the document. Useful indeed.   I've added another equation in the OP, in which there is an upside down triangle: How do you read the triangle out which is not in the document?

Comment: @NewPlanet that is not one I use but I believe it is called a nabla.

Comment: @NewPlanet I might be misremembering from college but I think the inverted-delta symbol is pronounced "del" as in "del-squared phi-sub-n."

Comment: Also, regarding the original question: the proper reading is "the partial derivative with respect to time of..." but when discussing it out loud people often say "dee-dee-tee..." instead. This is technically incorrect because the normal *d* and curved *d* are different functions, [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1435065) For the second derivative they don't usually shorten it that way, they say "the second partial derivative."

Comment: How do you pronounce the vertical line in the OP's picture (in the middle of the Schrodinger equation)? Simply "vertical line"? And in the end of the equation, there is a bent vertical line like >. How do you pronounce it?  Plus, the Hamiltonian operator H has a cap on it, how do you pronounce it?  I have noticed that some teachers write the equation without the vertical lines (including the bent line), which appears to be easier to understand. I don't know why the lines are inserted here.

Comment: The problem here is I am a statistician not a physicist so what we call them is probably not what physicists call them. I think it is best to remain silent rather than mislead you. Apologies.